# Loop through a navbar's list items and fade them in using jQuery's fadeIn() animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fadein, jquery-effects

What I'd like to do is iterate through a navigation's list items, and fade each element in, sequentially, but with the flexibility of having two delay options: the option to wait for each previous animation to complete before proceeding with the next animation, and/or a custom delay/timeout (milliseconds) between the start of each animation (not a delay between the end of one animation and the start of the next animation).

Naturally, I could use nested callbacks and call each list item specifically, but that's rather inefficient code-wise, and would only load each element one-after-another, which is okay in some cases, but in others I might want to have them load nearly simultaneously, with a possible slight delay (to emulate some of the Flash based navigations I've seen). Hense why I say that the custom delay option should be between the start of one, and the start of the next.

For what it's worth, the navigation elements are first being hidden via `$('#nav li').hide();` but I suspect you already guessed that might be the case. :)

How might this sort of effect be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#nav li').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).delay(index*50).fadeIn(400); // delays each subsequent fade by 50ms.
    // Change 50 to match the duration of the fade and they will fade in one after the other.
});
```

Comment: +1 Though I don't like fake-chaining animations by calculating a delay in this way, this is probably the best solution to implement both requirements at once.

Comment: This is a way cleaner solution!

Comment: @Yoshi: It's only fake-chaining if you are doing something asynchronous :P for something like an animation you're simply queuing a delay "animation" as part of the Fx queue, completely synchronous.

Comment: @Interrobang The reason I don't like it, is because if you're having a lot of heavy animations on a somewhat slow machine you'll see that the calulated delay method will become asynchronous. Whereas properly chained animations won't. I know this is more theoretically, but your first customer complaining about it, will teach you not to do it. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi fair enough! Cheers for the info.

Comment: Simple, clean. Just what I was looking for. I tested it, and it works quite well, at least in my case. The delays don't hinder the execution of the code following this loop either, which is nice. Thanks @Interrobang!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPbw4/7/

Suppose your nav HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item-1</li>
    <li>Item-2</li>
    <li>Item-3</li>
</ul>
```

Then your JS code for the serial animation can be something like this:

```
var currentLi = null;

var speed = 1000;
var gap = 500;

function doNext() {
    if(currentLi==null) {
        currentLi = $('ul li:first');
    }
    else if(currentLi.next().length!=0) {
        currentLi = currentLi.next();
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        currentLi.fadeIn(speed, doNext);
    }, gap);
}

doNext();
```

In the above code, `speed` is the animation speed and `gap` is the delay between each `fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple iteration like this

```
(function(wait, speed) {

  var itm = $('#nav li'),
      len = itm.length,
      index = 0;

  (function sequentialFade() {
      $.when( itm.eq(index).fadeIn(speed) )
       .done(function() {
           if (index++ === len) return false;
           setTimeout(function() {
               sequentialFade()
           }, wait);
       })
  }());


}(1000, 200))
```

In this case I used deferred objects (jQuery 1.5+), but the idea behind this approach is to wait the end of the fadein on the `n`th item and then iterate the function after `time` milliseconds on the `n+1`th item.

a JsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/McLZ4/3

Comment: In most cases, I will want them to appear faster than one-by-one, so not having the option to behave that way is a deal breaker.